# Ckan extention error using ckanext-restricted

Tags: command-line-interface, ckan

I'm new at creating data systems using CKAN, I just want to know if i'm doing the exact thing.

I've found a repo extention in github https://github.com/EnviDat/ckanext-restricted
and I want that to my system, I follow the steps
in installing `ckanext-restricted` I put it in `. /usr/lib/ckan/default/src` and type

```
git clone https://github.com/espona/ckanext-restricted.git
cd ckanext-restricted
python setup.py develop
pip install -r dev-requirements.txt
```

and I added `restricted` in `ckan.plugins` in my
`/etc/ckan/default/ckan.ini` and when a restart my system by typing
`sudo supervisorctl reload` then
`sudo supervisorctl status`

and the status look like below

```
ckan-datapusher:ckan-datapusher-00   RUNNING   pid 15888, uptime 0:23:24
ckan-uwsgi:ckan-uwsgi-00             RUNNING   pid 15889, uptime 0:23:24
ckan-worker:ckan-worker-00 FATAL Exited too quickly (process log may have details)
```

and when a refresh my system it's say "Internal server error". I'm really stock, I'm a newbie in CKAN. Any advice will be appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

i guess you are using sudo to install the extension.

I also got this error, when installing my own extension using sudoer user.

You can login as root before activating virtualenv, and do the rest under root user

by default, sudo does not carry virtualenv environment variables, aliases, functions, etc